# Error when using import randint in python

Tags: python, import

```
File "ex43.py", line 2, in <module>
    from random import randint
ImportError: cannot import name randint
```

Any suggestions for the `randint` error?  I tried reinstalling python, with no luck.

Comment: `import random; print(random.__file__)` - what does it print?

Comment: can you please show the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 4):

Check any `random.py` or `random.pyc` file(which will override python `random`) in the current folder where `ex43.py` resides.If there, delete or rename that files.Also check import by

```
>>>import random
>>>print(random.__file__)
```

Check it is importing from packages

Comment: I am still very new and not understanding all this, I do have a random.py and random.pyc in the folder.  Not sure what I would do to check these.  There is no randint file in their though.

Comment: When I run that, after deleting the random.py and random.pyc, I end up with this.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: cannot import name log

Comment: :).so delete or rename `math.py` and `math.pyc` as you did for `random.py` in current directory